# Ember store (using localstorage adapter) data is lost after browser refresh

Tags: ember.js, local-storage, ember-data

I configured my Ember App to run with the localstorage_adapter.

I am new to Ember and probably, I don't grasp all its details yet. Still, from what I understand, when you refresh the browser the ember store data should not be lost. Obviously the localstorage is not affected by a browser refresh.

This is what happens:
1. after login, I fetch the data from the server and store it using store.push() or store.pushMany()
2. play around with the application
3. at some point hit a browser refresh (or on my Android phone when I hit the home button, the browser get's closed and when I open it again from the running applications window, it opens and does a refresh by default)
4. the page which I was on gets messed up

For example, I'm on page where I display the user name, a question and a list of possible answers. Please note that there are 20+ questions in store. I know this by using Ember Inspector. I hit refresh, now the store has 1 user entity (the logged user) which is fine, 1 question only (not good at all), the one which was displayed on the page, and the answers store is empty. All other entities (which have nothing to do with this page) are gone too! So what I can see on my web page is the user name and the question's text, no answers, no way to move forward.

Is this supposed to happen? The "in memory" store gets cleared and not repopulated from localstorage?

thanks!

Comment: Are you saving the records anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this supposed to happen? The "in memory" store gets cleared and not repopulated from localstorage?

Yes, it is supposed to happen. To understand why, first remember that the localStorage in your browser is seen *as a server*. To Ember-Data, there's absolutely no difference between your localStorage and a Rails server with a REST API. Ember-Data treats them both as asynchronous data stores that it communicates with through an adapter. The LocalStorageAdapter is no different.

What does this mean? It means that your store only gets populated with records that you specifically request. Just as Ember-Data doesn't try to get all of the records from a Rails server at startup, it doesn't try to get all of the records from your localStorage at startup. *This is by design.* Ember-Data doesn't play favorites; it treats all adapters equally.

In order to repopulate your store with entries from the localStorage, use the store's `find()` method like you would in any other situation. The calls with be quick, although still asynchronous.

Also, as Beerlington mentioned, you must save your data explicitly if you want it to go into the localStorage. The store won't place it there automatically.

Comment: Ok, this means that if I refresh, the route will get reloaded and the model hook will be called. I return store.findAll('question'). And in my view I start to iterate the questions.. the thing is that a question has many answers, but they don't get loaded. And I cannot see them in my view. The models are ok a question hasMany answers. What am I missing?

Comment: If a question `hasMany` answers, you'll need to load them separately. Usually using them in a template will load them for you. If you have an issue loading the answers, or putting them in the template, feel free to post a another question that's a bit more specific.